# Induction Coil Diameter

Tags: inductance

I am currently building an induction heater to anneal brass casings. I have bought a 1000W induction heater with coil and a 36V 16.6A PSU to run it.

Everything works well, I can put in a screwdriver and heat it to 600*c in a matter of seconds, but once I put in a piece of brass it takes it a very long time to reach over 100*c

The coil is 508mm in diameter, and has 7 coils.

Doing a quick calculation,

```
my Inductance = 0.201 microhenries

Working: 
(600W - 100W) x 3.32s = 1660J 
1660J ÷ 10.95g ÷ 0.38J/g°C = 398.94°C
```

It should take me just over 3 seconds to reach 398°C/750°F but it won't reach over 100°C

What should I change to improve heating, should I remake my coil to a smaller diameter?
My brass is 1cm in diameter and very thin.

Comment: Figure out some way to make your brass casting  look like a shorted turn when it's in the field.

Comment: @EMFields Sorry, I dont follow what you mean by "look like a shorted turn" I am very new to this.

Comment: When you say "very thin" do you mean it's a thin walled tube, or a very thin disk? How thin exactly? If it's thin enough its resistance will be high, limiting the induced current, limiting the heating power. And its thermally conducting area is large compared to its mass and heating power, effectively cooling it.

Comment: @BrianDrummond It is thin walled tube, 0.5mm thick.

Comment: For annealing your brass for reloading, try a smaller coil as in [this](http://forum.accurateshooter.com/threads/induction-brass-annealer-redux.3908353/) link. You're reloading .40 caliber pistol rounds?

Answer (score 1):

The metal in a screwdriver is ferromagnetic meaning it is very magnetic. Iron cobalt and nickel are the most ferromagnetic metals. If you want to melt brass make a melting pot out of iron.